# SQL pulling data based on date

Tags: php, html, sql, datetime

I have a database full of store information and personal transactions. I have two webpages. One takes user input for the store name and runs a query pulling all transaction info for that store. I have another page almost identical that takes input for a start date and an end date and then runs a query for transactions between that date. The one for the store name works perfectly, but the one for the date doesn't display anything. I am still learning html/php/sql but I know exactly how the first page works so I cannot see why the same doesn't work for the second. If someone could help me, I'd appreciate it.

Here is my first page for the store name search that works.

```
<?php

$transaction = $_REQUEST["StoreName"];

    require_once 'login.php';

    $connection = mysqli_connect(
           $db_hostname, $db_username,
           $db_password, $db_database);



       $sql = "SELECT * FROM PURCHASE WHERE StoreName LIKE '%".$transaction."%'";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);

    ?>

    Purchases Made From <?php echo $transaction ?>
<table border="2" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
                  <th width="15%">Item Name</th>
                  <th width="15%">Item Price</th> 
                  <th width="15%">Purchase Time</th>
                  <th width="15%">Purchase Date</th>
                  <th width="15%">Category</th>
                  <th width="15%">Rating</th>
                </tr>
</table>
     <?php
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            // output data of each row
            while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
               <table border="2" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['ItemName']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['ItemPrice']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['PurchaseTime']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['PurchaseDate']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo      $rows['PurchaseCategory']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['Rating']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

And here is the page for the date search that returns no data.

```
<?php

$startDate = $_REQUEST["StartDate"];
$endDate = $_REQUEST["EndDate"];

    require_once 'login.php';

    $connection = mysqli_connect(
           $db_hostname, $db_username,
           $db_password, $db_database);



       $sql = "SELECT * FROM PURCHASE WHERE PurchaseDate BETWEEN '%".$startDate."%' and '%".$endDate."%'";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);

    ?>

    Purchases Made Between <?php echo $startDate ?> and <?php echo $endDate ?>
<table border="2" style="width:100%">
    <tr>
                  <th width="15%">Item Name</th>
                  <th width="15%">Item Price</th> 
                  <th width="15%">Purchase Time</th>
                  <th width="15%">Purchase Date</th>
                  <th width="15%">Category</th>
                  <th width="15%">Rating</th>
                </tr>
</table>
     <?php
        if($result->num_rows > 0){
            // output data of each row
            while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
               <table border="2" style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['ItemName']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['ItemPrice']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['PurchaseTime']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['PurchaseDate']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['PurchaseCategory']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['Rating']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Obviously the initial search pages that link to both of these output pages differ a bit more but I can confirm that the date output page is receiving the correct dates from the search page.

EDIT: Here is the search page for the date.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Output 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Required Output 2</h1>
<h2>Transaction Search By Date</h2>
<br/>
<br/>

<form action="outputout2.php" method="get">
Start Date: <input type="date" name="StartDate">
End Date: <input type="date" name="EndDate">
<input name="Add Merchant" type="submit" value="Search">
</form>;

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see name attributes for both `StartDate` and `EndDate`. closest related I see is `<td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['PurchaseTime']; ?></td>
                    <td width="15%"><?php echo $rows['PurchaseDate']; ?></td>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just updated the question with the search page code.

Comment: all I can think of as to why it would fail would be the column types and what values you're passing in there.

Comment: see Ollie's answer, that makes sense

Comment: @Fred-ii- he explained why I should not use the % operator but he did not say what the alternative was. How can I call the variable in the sql statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of problem is usually the result of misformatted dates.

Your query, if I'm reading it right, says this when you've finished assembling it in php and sent it to the SQL server:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM PURCHASE                   --wrong!
  WHERE PurchaseDate BETWEEN '%5/1/2016%' and '%5/8/2016%'
```

This is not going to work.

For one thing, the `%` signs only work with the `LIKE` operator, not on equality and inequality operators.

For another thing, different makes and models of database server software use differently formatted date strings.  MySQL and SQL Server will work fine with string formats like `2016-05-01`. But you have to look up the appropriate ways of doing this for the kind of SQL software product you are using. This kind of stuff is not very vendor-portable.

Third: your `PurchaseDate` column in your table needs to have a date-like datatype for this kind of thing to work.

Fourth: if your `PurchaseDate` items are timestamps -- that is, if that have both dates and times -- you can't reliably use the `BETWEEN` operator.  Here's why:  Suppose you have a value of `2016-05-08 11:50:00`  When you compare that to an end date `2016-05-08`, it lies beyond the end date.  So, what you really need is this:

```
 WHERE PurchaseDate >= '2016-05-01'
   AND PurchaseDate <  '2016-05-09' -- the day AFTER your end date
```

That construct performs the same as `BETWEEN` and doesn't screw up the last days' data.

**Edit** so it's MySQL you're using.

Workbench is a client program. So is PHP. The server is MySQL.  When you do an operation like

```
     DateColumn < 'string constant'
```

MySQL implicitly converts the `string constant` to a date. If the format of the string constant is close enough to [ISO 8601](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html) for the server to figure out what it means, it will convert it.  `2016-12-13` is exactly right.  `2016-5-31` is close enough for MySQL, and so is `2016-5-5`.  `2016/12/31` doesn't work. Neither does `5/5/16`.

Germane to your question is this: MySQL cannot convert `%2016-5-5%` (with the percent signs) to a date.

When MySQL can't convert a date, it comes up with NULL. [Comparisons with NULL values are weird](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html).  And, in the immortal words of Hunter S. Thompson, ["when the going gets weird, the weird turn pro"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Hunter_S._Thompson#1970s).  NULL weirdness is probably the root cause of your empty result set in the query you showed.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did not know most of that.  I am using MySQLWorkbench which uses the 2016-5-5 format which is how the site is inputting the data so I think the formatting is good. And `PurchaseDate` is set as `date` in the database. My issue might be with the SQL statement. If I cannot use the % sign, how can I call the variable in the statement?

Comment: Thank you, I understand that I cannot use the % signs because it cannot convert to the proper format. But if I am calling the date from a  variable, what is the proper format to use instead? Plugging in the variable names without the signs don't work either.